# blank page and fatal error after migration

Tags: magento-1.7

After migration I have a blank page and this error.log

Class `'Mage_Paypal_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /home/urbanqua/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 234`

How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it is trying to load the Paypal setup file from within the core setup php file. I'd go see if the file app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Resource\Setup.php exists and has the magento core code, which from what I can tell is just an empty class that extends the Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup class. I would also dig into the file that is throwing the error and see if you can put in something that will log bits about what is being passed that may help with tracking down the error a little bit more. Maybe add something like this just before line 234 in that file to help see what may be causing the error a bit more?

```
Mage::log($className);
Mage::log($resName);
```